# preg_match error handling not working

Tags: php, error-handling

My php error handling appears to not be working and I have no idea I have looked for hours for a reason and just cannot put my finger on it. My html is linked correctly and the php form runs. Also the error handling for 'telephone' works just fine, therefor there must be a problem with my preg_match as that is the only common thing between the non working errors? I know it will probably be something really simple and i'm over looking it but I have looked as much as I can.  #### NOTE: I have all ready tried other types of strings and literals and changed my code from if(!preg_match($string_exp,!first_name) ect and it still does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated. The form should handle these errors and output the error message but it does not.

```
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(preg_match($string_exp,$first_name) == 0) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  } 

  if(preg_match($string_exp,$last_name) == 0) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
     $food_expected = "0";
  if(preg_match($food_expected,$formFood) == 0) { 
     $error_message .= 'Please select a Food.'; 
} 

  if(strlen($telephone) > 11) {
    died($error_message); }
  if(strlen($telephone) < 11 ) {
    died($error_message);
  }
```

Comment: You've dumped 100+ lines of code and you neither explain how it fails to work and nor provide sample input to reproduce the issue. If you really have problems composing a regular expression, I'm pretty sure you can edit the question and replace all that code with a 2 line snippet.

Comment: If your user types a non-English name (such as `Álvaro`) you write something into `$error_message`. How should that abort form processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the PHP manual page for preg_match() [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), it has the following to say:

> **Warning**
> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

I would suggest that you start by testing the return value of your `preg_match` against false with the `===` operator:

```
if (preg_match($string_exp,$first_name) === false)
```

to find out whether there is a problem with your regular expression.

In any case, do not use the `==` operator here.

Having said which, in the unedited version of your question, if the telephone number is 11 characters long, the `died()` function never gets called with the `$error_message`, even if the `preg_match()` returns 0.